# Disabled "Generate Local Resource" in Visual Studio 2010 Premium

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can anyone please help me understand why the "Generate Local Resource" option is disabled in my Visual Studio 2010 (premium version)?  I have a simple Website and first of all I couldn't find the option in the menu, then I figured how to show it in the menu but is's always disabled... I'm going crazy with this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Make sure that your page is open in Page Design View.**

This option is a designer-based command, and will always be disabled unless you are in the design view with your page fully loaded.

Comment: But that makes me wonder why it is even in the menu when on code view in the first place... Very stupid why they can't make it just work for both views.

Comment: In case of still grey when in design mode, try to focus a control first

Answer (score 3):

In my case (using Visual studio 2012), the option is sometimes greyed out even when in design view. To fix it, just switch to source view and back to design view again.